# Change built-in Document properties without opening

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am attempting to run the below line of code in a sub. The purpose of the sub overall is to automatically create agendas for recurring meetings, and notify the relevant people.

```
'Values for example;
MtgDate = CDate("11/06/2020")
Agenda ="Z:\Business Manual\10000 Management\11000 Management\11000 Communications\Operations Meetings\11335 - OPS CCAR Performance Review Agenda 11.06.20.docx" 'NB it's a string

'and the problematic line:
Word.Application.Documents(Agenda).BuiltinDocumentProperties("Publish Date") = MtgDate
```

Two questions:

1) Can I assign a document property just like that without opening the document? (bear in mind this vba is running from an excel sheet where the data is stored)

2) Will `word.application.documents` accept the document name as a string, or does it have to be some other sort of object or something? I don't really understand Word VBA.

Attempts so far have only resulted in

> runtime error 427 "remote server machine does not exist or is
>   unavailable"

or something about a bad file name.

Comment: How do you define `MtgDate`? If it's a date variable, then you need something like `MtgDate = CDate("11/06/2020")` instead, because what you have now is actually `11 divided by 6 divided by 2020` - Which is not a date

Comment: @ braX Sorry you're correct. As mentioned, those variables are pulled from other places in the excel sheet, I only declared them on there for example purposes. Just editing the question to reflect that, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: `BuiltinDocumentProperties` are read-only, so you cannot set them to anything. Are you maybe trying to set `CustomDocumentProperties`?

Comment: And as for syntax.... `Debug.Print ActiveDocument.BuiltinDocumentProperties(wdPropertyWords)` for example

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.builtindocumentproperties

Comment: A really doubt you are able to change even the custom ones without opening the document, if that's the question.

Comment: @braX Thanks for that, yes I guess that does answer it. I think my best alternative now is to add a custom property and set that, and then figure if it can be done without opening the document. MTs for your help.

Comment: see here and scroll down: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/docprop.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Publish Date can be found under Insert > Quick Parts > Document Property it isn't actually a document property. It is a "built-in" CustomXML part, a node of CoverPageProperties, and can be addressed in VBA using the CustomXMLParts collection.

The CustomXML part is only added to the document once the mapped content control is inserted.

Below is the code I use.

As already pointed out for document properties the document must be open.

```
Public Sub WriteCoverPageProp(ByVal strNodeName As String, ByVal strValue As String, _
        Optional ByRef docTarget As Document = Nothing)
  '*  Nodes:    Abstract, CompanyAddress, CompanyEmail, CompanyFax, CompanyPhone, PublishDate
  '*  NOTE: If writing PublishDate set the content control to store just the date (default is date and time).
  '*        The date is stored in the xml as YYYY-MM-DD so must be written in this format.
  '*        The content control setting will determine how the date is displayed.
  Dim cxpTarget                   As CustomXMLPart
  Dim cxnTarget                   As CustomXMLNode
  Dim strNamespace                As String

  If docTarget Is Nothing Then Set docTarget = ActiveDocument

  strNodeName = "/ns0:CoverPageProperties[1]/ns0:" & strNodeName
  strNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/coverPageProps"
  Set cxpTarget = docTarget.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace(strNamespace).item(1)
  Set cxnTarget = cxpTarget.SelectSingleNode(strNodeName)
  cxnTarget.Text = strValue

  Set cxnTarget = Nothing
  Set cxpTarget = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify a document without opening it. In any event, "Publish Date" is not a Built-in Document Property; if it exists, it's a custom one.

Contrary to what you've been told, not all BuiltinDocumentProperties are read-only; some, like wdPropertyAuthor ("Author"), are read-write.

Answer (score 1):

There are three main ways you could modify a Word document or "traditional" property (which are the ones you can access via .BuiltInDocumentProperties and .CustomProperties):

a. via the Object Model (as you are currently trying to do)

b. for a .docx, either unzipping the .docx, modifying the relevant XML part, and re-zipping the .docx.

c. For "traditional" properties, i.e. the things that you can access via .BuiltInDocumentProperties and .CustomDocumentProperties, in theory you can use a Microsoft .dll called dsofile.dll. But it hasn't been supported for a long time, won't work on Mac Word and the Microsoft download won't work on 64-bit Word. You'd also have to distribute and support it.

But in any case, "Publish Date" is not a traditional built-in property. It's probably, but not necessarily, a newer type of property called a "Cover Page Property". Those properties are in fact pretty much as "built-in" as the traditional properties but cannot be accessed via .BuiltInDocumentProperties.

To modify Cover Page properties, you can either use the object model or method (b) to access the Custom XML Part in which their data is stored. Method (c) is no help there.

Not sure where your error 427 is coming from, but I would guess from what you say that you are trying to see if you can modify the property in a single line, using the fullname of the document in an attempt to get Word to open it. No, you can't do that - you have to use GetObject/CreateObject/New to make a reference to an instance of Word (let's call it "wapp"), then (say)

```
Dim wdoc As Word.Document ' or As Object
Set wdoc = wapp.Documents.Open("the fullname of the document")
```

*Then* you can access its properties, e.g. for the read/write Title property you can do

```
wdoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title") = "your new title"
wdoc.Save
```

If Publish Date is the Cover Page Property, once you have a reference to the Word Application and have ensured the document is open you can use code along the following lines:

```
Sub modPublishDate(theDoc As Word.Document, theDate As String)
' You need to format theDate - by default, Word expects an xsd:dateTime,
' e.g. 2020-06-11T00:00:00 if you only care about the date.
Const CPPUri As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/coverPageProps"
Dim cxn As Office.CustomXMLNode
Dim cxps As Office.CustomXMLParts
Dim nsprefix As String
Set cxps = theDoc.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace(CPPUri)
If cxps.Count > 0 Then
  With cxps(1)
    nsprefix = .NamespaceManager.LookupPrefix(CPPUri)
    Set cxn = .SelectSingleNode(nsprefix & ":CoverPageProperties[1]/" & nsprefix & ":PublishDate[1]") '/PublishDate[1]")
    If Not (cxn Is Nothing) Then
      cxn.Text = theDate 
      Set cxn = Nothing
    End If
  End With
End If
Set cxps = Nothing
```

As for this, "Will word.application.documents accept the document name as a string", the answer is "yes", but Word has to have opened the document already. as mentioned above. Word can also accept an integer index into the .Documents collection and may accept just the name part of the FullName string.

Finally, if you do end up using a "traditional Custom Document Property", even after you have set the property and saved the document (approximately as above) you may find that the new property value has not actually saved! If so, that's down to an old error in Word where it won't save unless you have actually visited the Custom Document Property Dialog or have modified the document content in some way, e.g. adding a space at the end.